# Inconsistency between number of records returned and count(*) result

Tags: sql, count, oracle10g

I'm using Oracle 10g and I'm having a inconsistency problem, in the following query I get 6746 records if I do the select * but if I do a count(*) I get only 1361 records counted:

```
SELECT  *
    from TOTALD.TOT_IN A, TOTALD.TOT_CE B
    WHERE FECHA >= TO_DATE(NVL(NULL, '01/01/2012'),'DD/MM/YYYY')
    AND     FECHA <= TO_DATE(NVL('17/07/2012', sysdate),'DD/MM/YYYY')
    AND (A.ID_CE = B.ID_CE
    OR  A.ID_CE IS NULL)
    AND A.ID_EST = '1';
```

I need to get the count in addition for the records, for calculations.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `FECHA` belong to both tables?  (Older versions of Oracle would sometimes allow ambiguous SQL statements, and would just randomly pick one table.  Maybe it's using a different table for each statement?)  Also, you can simplify the first two predicates using `BETWEEN` and ANSI date literals: `FECHA between date '2012-01-01' and date '2012-07-17'`

Comment: Look at the explain plan results for each query (or post them here) and it'll show you where the discrepancy is happening.

Comment: Are you sure you're only changing the SELECT clause? Are you running both queries in SQL*Plus? Are there any other sessions doing DML on the instance around the same time? Are TOT_IN and TOT_CE both tables, or are they views (that might call a stored procedure to generate rows)?

Answer (score 1):

`sql%rowcount` should return the number of rows affected by your query. Then you don't need to run it twice

Comment: Thanks podiluska, but actually, I only run it once, what I actually need is the count, but I used the "select *" in my testing because I was getting wrong values with the count.